# Lazily added routes are not accessible by url

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

When component introduces new route for its router-view it is working while going trough the app, but once you refresh or try to access url directly it does not load. I assume that it is because of the fact that component adding routes did not add them yet.

But I would expect that router would parse url by its segments, match parent component, loads it (which introduces child routes) and then continue with next segment. Or something similar.

Is there a way how to achieve routing added lazily? So each loaded module introduce its part (module) of a router? But in same time they can be accessed by url?

Thanks

Here is reproduced issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-router-lazy-route-5opufo
Click on Admin link and then settings, it works, try to access admin/settings by url, it does not load settings content.

EDIT:
Here what I expect https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwnzjg
ATTENTION it fails on stackblitz, but you can download the project, install dependencies and try it yourself to see that it works correctly.
After start dev server, navigate directly to http://localhost:4200/customers/profile as you can see, it works even the fact that the router part targeted is loaded lazily in Customers module.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `admin` and then click on `settings`, the code run follows this scenario:

```
Click admin -> router resolved (found admin component) -> admin component setup -> you dynamic add settings router 
-> click settings -> router resolved (found settings component) -> load settings component successfully
```

But when you reload the browser on the `/admin/settings` route, the scenario will be:

```
Reload page '/admin/settings' -> router resolved (found admin component but NOT the settings component because admin component's setup code is not run yet)
-> only load admin component
```

In this scenario, the `admin` component's setup code will be run after the router is resolved. So the dynamic adding router code is not run at that time and the router can NOT resolve the `settings` component

### Solution

Move your dynamic adding router code to beforeEach navigation guard so it can be run every time the router resolved

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  const hasRoute = router.hasRoute(to.name || "");

  if (to.path === "/admin/settings" && !router.hasRoute(to.name || "")) {
    router.addRoute("admin", {
      path: "settings",
      name: "settings",
      component: { template: "<div>AdminSettings</div>" }
    });
    // Don't forget to return the router here to make sure the router will be correctly resolved
    return { name: "settings" };
  }
});
```

Comment: But this solution requires that app needs to know full routing tree at the beginning, it cannot be partially loaded lazily. I am looking for something like angular router does: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules
It loads module with chunk of routes and it just works out of the box.
Here is reproduction https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwnzjg. ATTENTION it fails on stackblitz, but you can download the project, install dependencies and try it yourself to see that it works correctly.. I would like to have same behaviour in vue router.

Comment: @Luckylooke Why do you need to add your route dynamically? Just think about the business simply. If you want to use a route, you must add it first. So you can not get it to work on the reloading page because you didn't add it to the router.

Comment: Because adding app parts dynamically is scalable pattern. In angular way you have no limits. Condition to know whole app routing in initial chunk is imho not good pattern. Let's say I have base app, and then admin app in separate repos and devteams, whenever admin app team changes router they need to ask main app team to update routing? When I distribute updated admin app I need to always distribute new main app,  because of new routing. Also if admin app can add new subpages to main app (into db). Main app reads db and updates routing according to changes in db. Not possible in vue router.

Comment: The pattern base app and additional chunks in a separate repo sound interesting. But I don't see how can it happened. Let's say we can solve this dynamic routing problem but how can Vue know where the file of code to load when visiting a route? Because the file is placed in another repo so Vue has no information about it. So we have to end up by pushing all the code together. Then at that time, you don't need dynamic routing anymore, right?

Comment: We had API for apps in one of my previous projects, it was angular environment and child app was loaded in routing guard, therefore I am looking for same option/pattern in Vue, as I love the scalability of pattern.. I love scalable patterns in general  maybe my diagnose 